# How can I find the objective best ad network for my case?

Tags: advertising

I have a site with over 3 million visits a month but I'm not sure which ad network is best for me. I'm with Ezoic now, paying $3-11k monthly for their premium program, with about a 50% ROI. Ezoic helps with caching and CDN, cutting costs, but I've had issues with site performance and ads causing crashes on mobile.

I can't switch networks easily due to an exclusive contract with Ezoic, so I'm thinking of hiring an ad ops expert to help me evaluate options. How should I go about finding someone impartial to guide me?

Answer (score 1):

Until you're done with your contract (I'm guessing it's a 3-year contract), you can't migrate from Ezoic.

I use Ezoic on a couple of sites, and it does pay better than other networks (Adsense for example), but I can't say I'm a fan of all the other stuff they add to the mix. (YMMV)

Once you are free to move, there are several other networks out there that can be more beneficial, however, the only true way to know is to apply for them and test them for a while. For example, doing A/B testing for 2 weeks.

Top of the list are Mediavine, Outbrain and Taboola, however each has their own minimum requirements to be able to join.

Note that there are LOTS of other networks, some are more specialized than others, some only work in specific geographies (United States for example), etc.